# Multithreading, Queues, GUIs, and Listeners

Tags: python, user-interface, queue, python-multithreading

I have something I am trying to setup. I'll try and provide a small sub-example here.

My project goal is to run a GUI and run a ROS listener that listens for changes and then outputs them to the GUI on button clicks and stuff.

Here is an example of my setup

main.py

```
from PyQt5 import *
from Gui_UI import * # This is my GUI class
from Listener_Class import * # This is my Listener class

def launch_gui(q) :
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Gui_UI(q)
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "main":
    ## A bunch of stuff to setup my ROS nodes and other random things I need to do
    q = queue.Queue()
    t2 = threading.Thread( target=Gui_UI, args=(q) )
    t2.start()
    launch_gui(q)
```

Then my Gui_UI.py is just

```
## Tons of imports including
import queue
import threading
import PyQt5

class Gui_UI(object) :
    def __init__(self, q) :
        self.q = q

    def return_var_using_queue() :
       my_var = q.get() 
       UI_object_I_want_to_displa_this_in.setPlaceholderText(my_var)
```

Finally my Listener_Class.py

```
## Tons of imports including
import queue
import threading
import rospy

class Listener_Class(object) :
    def __init__(self, q) :
        self.q = q

    def send_var_to_UI() :
         var = 5
         q.put(var)
```

So the issue is once I click the button that calls that function, I get NameError: name 'q' is not defined.

I have my guesses as to exactly why that is, but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

I need to have each of these as their own separate class running in separate threads, since they're both continuously running and I do not want them to lock each other up, and need them running simultaneously.

Comment: Why is `launch_qui` being passed `q` as its argument that is then used to construct a `Gui_UI` instance instead of being passed the already-constructed `Gui_UI` instance that is running as thread?

Comment: You do not show how `Listener_Class` get instantiated nor do you show where you are getting your error. You need to include a stacktrace and the code that it references.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: we need to be able to reproduce this to find out your problem

Answer (score 4):

`q` doesn't exist indeed:

```
class Listener_Class(object) :
    def __init__(self, q) :
        self.q = q

    def send_var_to_UI() :
         var = 5
         q.put(var)
```

In the `__init__` you define `self.q`, so you should change the `send_var_to_UI` method to:

```
    def send_var_to_UI(self) :
         var = 5
         self.q.put(var)
```

Comment: Not only that, but probably under `return_var_using_queue()` you might want to change it to `my_var = self.q.get()`. Also, another way of implementing threads that might benefit you is one I was working on today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932804/can-i-call-a-thread-recurrently-from-within-a-thread)